# Bing Map : generate local map tiles for US zip codes, counties, states in C# WPF Visual Studio 2013

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, bing-maps

I am trying to generate local map tiles for US states, counties and zipcodes so that I can mark them as polygons on Bing Map from C# Visual Studio 2013 WPF on win 7.

I am following the instructions at:

https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/08/24/local-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-wpf

http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/redmond/projects/mapcruncher/tutorial/version3.0docs/index.htm

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427619.aspx

I am tring to use thr MapCruncher make the tiles. But, I do not know how to get an image for a state, county, or zip code such that I can use the MapCruncher to get the map tiles.

I need images of them without borders because an image is normally a square with some white bounds around the state , county, or zip code polygon area.

Also, because I need to make all local map tiles for all US states, counties and zip codes. It is impossible to make them manually by the MapCruncher tool.

How to make them by MapCruncher code ? Or are there C# codes that can do these ?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

From the link of

https://xyllyg.dm2302.livefilestore.com/y3mmTyuxpIVtzGHj0t4gvQwZND2Ei2-lqB-TsyjedXzPnAujjXOMzKXnH5ZBjSO-47Ml2AOx1N5buA0iNxz_DfS7J9jn-hO_0Hxy2GG-BYwByJt7Z6LfWTXs7HDpaKG9vSpQuqPniJ6DVdddignj-3itM7VvWqnHOXoW6FESYMQ-No/Managing%20and%20Visualizing%20Geospatial%20Data%20with%20Bing%20Maps%20Whitepaper%20v01.pdf?psid=1

I have found the example in Section of "Thematic Maps from Bing SDS" at page 28.

But, the code example at https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Managing-and-Visualizing-f42fdd5c
requires Visual Studio 2015, Windows Azure Storage, Apache Cordova, Bing Spatial Data Services .

These are not available in my working environment. Are there examples of Visual Studio 2013 ?

Also, how to use your techniques in Section of "Thematic Maps from Bing SDS" for OpenStreetmap  ?

Comment: Cross posted: http://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=53062

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of different ways to do what you want to do. If you want to overlay raw boundaries on top of the map you likely will run into performance issues if you try to render more then a few hundred detailed polygons such as counties or Zip codes. If you only want to view this data when zoomed in close you could load in the data as needed for where the user is viewing. You could upload the boundary data into the Bing Spatial Data Services and easily retrieve it from there.

If you want to be able to view the data at all zoom levels, then turning your data into a tile layer would be the best option. Since the data you will be working with is in vector form (raw data, not an image), MapCruncher won't work for you. Instead you will need to do one of the following:

- Dynamically generate the tiles from the raw data on the fly. This will allow you to support all zoom levels without needing Petabyte's worth of storage. This is a great approach to use when you need tiles that cover a large area, or when the data changes regularly. In fact, the tiles used in Bing Maps do this as the storage requirements for 117 languages and all zoom levels would be in the 1000's of petabytes. I have a white paper outlining how to do this and code samples here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D35222484A76A01!361218&authkey=!AMEJsKW8h_HUbOg&ithint=file%2cpdf

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=D35222484A76A01!323177&authkey=!AId01rJ-JPDPZMw&ithint=file%2czip

- Use a tool to generate tiles from raw data. I have a code sample that does this here: http://mapstoolbox.codeplex.com/ Take a look at the WPF Spatial Data viewer. It allows you to load spatial data from different file formats and then generate map tiles out of it. Note that each zoom level has 4 times the map tiles as the zoom level before it. If you are looking to generate map tiles over the US, you will likely find that once you get to zoom level 8 or 9 you will need a lot of storage and the file system will likely be really slow. At that point you would need to look at storing the tiles in a database system to speed up querying the tiles. I would only recommend this approach if you only wanted tiles for a small area and a few zoom levels, otherwise the storage requirements will likely make this an unusable solution. If you do go this route you might want to look at storing the tiles in Azure blob storage as it is cheap and would allow you to store a lot of tiles much easier than you could on your local machine.

The dynamic tile approach would likely be your best option. You could try taking it a step further if you are only using WPF and generate the tiles in the app rather than in a web service, although using a web service would make it much easier to migrate your app to another platform in the future, such as Windows 10, or web. If you want to generate the tiles in the app, you can take the code from the white paper and integrate it with the code sample here:  https://blogs.bing.com/maps/2015/08/24/local-tile-layers-in-bing-maps-wpf/

Comment: You can't use OpenStreetMaps in a Bing Maps control. It is against the terms of use. As for VS 2015, you should be able to open the project in VS2013. The Azure part of the sample will likely be an issue, but you can remove that as you likely won't need it if you run and host the code locally.